# how to enable/disable asp.net validators on radio button click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validationgroup

i have asp.net form and several radio buttons on it, they contain nested radio buttons (see picture). TextBoxes have Validators.

The question is: how to disable necessary validators when corresponding radio button is unchecked and enable them when radio is checked?

i need to do it on client side by means of javascript.

[image]

Do i need to group validators into validation groups?

Any help is appreciated. Thanx in advance))

Answer (score 1):

```
if(radioButton.Checked)
{
    textBox1.required = false;
}
```

PS: `AutoPostBack` needs to be true for the radio button